# How to call mod_rewrite rules from a subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect call URLs to https (.htaccess at root):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301]
```

I want to call a subdirectory (`www.example.com/subdir`) and the rule to be executed, but it doesn't.
My Host force me to use `RewriteBase`, but I don't know if this is the problem.
The subdirectory has a .htaccess file too:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /php_ppadminsvc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA]
```

**Solution:** 
By removing the .htaccess file in the subdirectory the redirect at root works.

Comment: Sounds like you might have contradicting rules. Is the above all you have in your `.htaccess` or is there more?